# The content is not loaded when I try to do a Ajax call request in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a Ajax request using jQuery library but the content is not loading.

My main.js file is as below

```
$(function()
 {

//Loading static pages

         var loadSection=function(options)
         {  if (typeof options !== 'object')
              options= {};
            options.selector=options.selector || " ";
            options.url= options.url || " ";
            return  $.get(options.url, function(result)
                    {  $(options.selector).html(result)
                    },'html');
         }


  $('#Load').click(function()

  { $.when(
      loadSection({ selector: "#Section1", url: "Content1.html"}),
      loadSection({ selector: "#Section2", url: "Content2.html"}),
      loadSection({ selector: "#Section3", url: "Content3.html"})
  )
  .promise()
  .done(function()
    {
      $('#Proceed').removeAttr('disabled');
    })
    .fail(function(result)
    {  $("#Messages").append("Failure!<br />")
                     .append("Result: " + result.statusText + "<br />");
    });
 });
});

     /*  First way
     $('#Section1').load('Content1.html', function()
      {
       $('#Section2').load('Content2.html', function()
       {
        $('#Section3').load('Content3.html', function()
         {
          $('#Proceed').removeAttr('disabled');

           });
         });
      });
    */
```

index.html file is as below

```
<!doctype html>
  <html language="en">
    <head>
      <title>Deferred Proccessing 1</title>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="DeferredStyles.css" />
      <script src="scripting/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body>
     <input id="Load" type="Button" value="Load" />
     <div id="Section1" ></div>
     <div id="Section2"></div>
     <div id="Section3"></div>
     <input id="Proceed" type="Button" value="Proceed" disabled="true" />
      <div id="Messages">
       </div>
  </body>
  <script src="scripting/main.js"></script>

 </html>
```

Content1.html is as below

```
<div id="Content1">
 This is content #1
</div>
```

The same is for Content2.html and Content3.html.

I am trying to figure it out why when I press button "Load" the content in the sections is not loaded. Also when I try the first way which is commented in my main.js the content is also not loaded. I have been working on it for two days and still do not understand what is going wrong. I need some help

Comment: Try this way
 when(1)..promise().done(function()
    { append-data when(2)..promise().done(function()
    { append-data  when(3)..promise().done(function()
    { append-data }) }) });

Comment: Your code **[works fine here](http://plnkr.co/edit/i69f8571Yh2T9EJsMIIe?p=preview)**. Any errors in console? Have you inspected the actual requests in browser dev tools console? Is `fail()` firing?

Comment: did you made sure the function is called and result hold the data as expected?